# How do you specify the requirements for 3-phase load center (breaker box)

Tags: current, three-phase, amperage

I have listed the eight required circuits in the image/table below. There are three 3-phase 208 V circuits, and five single-phase 120 V circuits. What I'm looking for specifically is how many amps should my load center be rated for (how do I calculate this)? And are there any additional requirements I should be looking for such as overall wattage?

As a bonus I am curious how to calculate the specifications for the electrical service that will be needed for these loads. Is this as simple as just the calculated current?

I'm a mechanical engineer so please be gentle. :)

| Phase | Amps | Voltage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | 120 |
| 1 | 20 | 120 |
| 3 | 30 | 208 |
| 1 | 20 | 120 |
| 1 | 20 | 120 |
| 1 | 20 | 120 |
| 3 | 60 | 208 |
| 3 | 60 | 208 |

Comment: You would rarely (if ever) calculate the required load center capacity simply by adding up the individual circuits supplied by that load center. What you're probably looking for is a "NEC Article 220 Load Calculation", which takes into account what is actually powered by all those individual circuits.

Comment: @brhans  True. But it is very likely that the real-world load of the 3-phase circuits is on the order of 70% - 80% of the stated circuit sizes. And since the 3-phase circuits account for most of the "add up the breakers" total, the likely true load calculation is most likely going to be pretty close to "add up the breakers" (with the 125% derate built in already).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table is a bit misleading - it's a tiny detail but important. Instead of the column label "Phase", it should be "# of Phases". That's the meaning of what you have:

| #Phases | Amps | Voltage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | 120 |
| 1 | 20 | 120 |
| 3 | 30 | 208 |
| 1 | 20 | 120 |
| 1 | 20 | 120 |
| 1 | 20 | 120 |
| 3 | 60 | 208 |
| 3 | 60 | 208 |

Then, you need to assign the single-phase loads to particular phases to balance everything out. Let's start with 3-phase loads. They naturally distribute across 3 phases:

| R | S | T | #Ph,Amps |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  | 1-30 |
|  |  |  | 1-20 |
| 30 | 30 | 30 | 3-30 |
|  |  |  | 1-20 |
|  |  |  | 1-20 |
|  |  |  | 1-20 |
| 60 | 60 | 60 | 3-60 |
| 60 | 60 | 60 | 3-60 |

Now we assign single-phase loads to phases so that the loads are spread evenly (balanced) across phases:

| R | S | T | #Ph,Amps |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30 |  |  | 1-30 |
|  | 20 |  | 1-20 |
| 30 | 30 | 30 | 3-30 |
|  | 20 |  | 1-20 |
|  |  | 20 | 1-20 |
|  |  | 20 | 1-20 |
| 60 | 60 | 60 | 3-60 |
| 60 | 60 | 60 | 3-60 |
| **180** | **190** | **190** | **TOTAL** |

> What I'm looking for specifically is how many amps should my load center be rated for

First of all, we needed phase assignments and a total current for each phase. The totals are below 200A, so a 200A load center would be a sufficient minimum just from the load current totals themselves. But there's more to it.

Now you'd want to look in the NEC and see if there is a requirement for providing additional capacity over this minimum. I don't recall off the top of my head.

> are there any additional requirements I should be looking for such as overall wattage?

Wattage - no. But utilization factor and extra capacity for future circuits that may be added should be taken into account. I highly suggest spending a day reading through the NEC.

> As a bonus I am curious how to calculate the specifications for the electrical service that will be needed for these loads. Is this as simple as just the calculated current?

Current and the utilization factors play a role. Utilization means how much of the maximum current capacity (circuit protection rating) the loads typically require. Many load centers, especially in residential service, are rated for smaller than 100% utilization. E.g. in my home, the panel is 200A, but there's about 300A worth of circuits attached to it. Most of those circuits, thankfully, are not loaded all the time, so it all works out.

A load center would have an input-side breaker rated for the total capacity of the center. So, hypothetically, if you expected only 30% utilization, perhaps a 100A center with a 100A main breaker per phase would work. The breakers for the circuits still add up to more than 100A, but in case the utilization rose above the expected value, the main breakers would turn the whole load center off.

I don't do this sort of design work often, so without NEC open, I'll leave it here. In spite of any other answers you get, do look into the NEC revision that applies to the location where this will be installed. For a NEC novice, a version with commentary may be appropriate. Since this is presumably commercial service, you'll want to keep it in mind. Requirements for commercial and residential installations differ.

Answer (score 3):

You need to ask how will these circuits be used.
The load center should be rated to meet or exceed the rating of the main breaker. The main breaker should generally be rated to match the service you have. The exception is that some very large services are normally used to feed multiple panels because breakers and panels over a certain size (think it's around 200A) start getting hard to find and expensive.

The big question is how big a service do you need? Adding up all the numbers as in Kuba's answer will generally result in an overkill solution but figuring out what you actually need can be tricky. You will find electrical standards come with tables but those tables aren't always appropriate to your situation (I know here in the UK they are explicitly labeled as guidelines rather than regulations, not sure about in the USA).

Firstly there is the question of equipment usage patterns. A one person workshop with manual machines may only need enough power, to run the air conditioning, small loads and one machine at any given time. A factory, or even a small workshop with CNC machines may need to run them all at the same time.

Secondly there is the questions of how much electricity the equipment *really* uses. Breakers only come in a set of standard sizes, so the circuit size is usually larger than what the appliance actually needs some equipment may rarely draw anywhere near it's full rated power.

There is also the question of what is available and at what price? if an overkill service costs only slightly more than a barely sufficient one then you may as well get it.

This is why you want someone with experience to do the design, so they can guide you to a solution, that is sufficient but not too much overkill.

Answer (score 3):

Another answer came up with 180 - 190 A per phase. I think that is basically correct and that points to a standard 200A load center.

But there is one very important key to this being correct: Circuit (breaker, wire) size vs. current used. Based on the wonderfully round numbers, it is a pretty safe bet here that the numbers listed (20, 30, 60) are the required circuit sizes. Some of those are likely way over - in particular, a typical 120V 20A circuit will have anywhere from 1A (lights) to 16A (large load *designed* for 80% of a 20A) circuit. The 3-phase loads are more likely designed to use somewhere between 60% and 80% of the circuit capacity. Why? Because there are only a handful of standard circuit sizes (so if a machine needs 21A you put in on the same 30A circuit as you would for a 24A machine), and because a *lot* of circuits have to be sized based on a derate for continuous load. What this generally means is the circuit is sized to 125% of the actual load, or (same thing but reverse) a circuit can only be loaded to 80% of the circuit capacity. Similar calculations relate to utility service feeder size vs. main breaker size and other sizing issues. The bottom line is that if the 20/30/60A values already account for this (i.e., continuous load no more than 16/24/48A) then 200A actually works out just fine.

All that being said, this does not leave a *lot* of excess capacity. Three-phase panels are readily available, but not generally on the low-price rack at Home Depot. In a quick look at Eaton CH - which is available in single-phase and three-phase (with the basic difference being a triple main breaker and three hots instead of a double main breaker and two hots) - there are 200A, 225A and 400A options. 400A gets very expensive and if you get to that point then 2 x 200A is usually a better choice. But 225A may make sense here as a way to have a bit of extra breathing room - enough to add another 20A or 30A three-phase circuit at least.